# AIX 7.1 su root password bug?

Tags: ssh, passwords, root, aix

In our AIX 7.1 machine there is a weird bug we've ran into..

If you are logged into the AIX box via SSH as a regular user and you try to su - you get prompted for the password, lets say our password is "P@$$w0rd23", you can type "P@$$w0rd2ANYTHING" and it will still grant you root.

As long as you have "P@$$w0rd2" it will grant you root regardless of what else you specify in the authentication and even though the actual password is "P@$$w0rd23".

This seems to be a bug? Anyone see anything like this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default AIX password algorithm is very weak, it uses only the first 8 characters of the password string.

But in AIX 7.1 stronger algorithms are also supported through Loadable Password Algorithm (LPA). Here is some docs:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-securityauthmeth/